# Trying to install PHP_Depend

Tags: php, pear

I'm trying to install PHP_Depend as here below but I'm getting that error you can see..

```
javier@javier-mbp:/var/www$ pear channel-discover pear.pdepend.org
Channel "pear.pdepend.org" is already initialized
javier@javier-mbp:/var/www$ pear remote-list -c pdepend
Channel pdepend Available packages:
===================================
Package                            Version
PHP_CodeSniffer_Standards_PDepend2 -n/a-
PHP_Depend                         0.10.6
PHP_Depend_Log_Arbit               1.0.0
staticReflection                   -n/a-
javier@javier-mbp:/var/www$ pear install pdepend/PHP_Depend
No releases available for package "pear.pdepend.org/PHP_Depend"
install failed
```

Any help?

Javi

Answer (score 3):

You no longer have to install the `-beta` package (as shown here - http://pear.pdepend.org/).

If you're still getting this error, you may have an issue with your pear cache.
Try running:

`pear clear-cache`

And then try installing again.

Another thing I'd like to make mention of: PHP_Depend is now available on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/pdepend/pdepend) as 'pdepend' via [Composer](http://getcomposer.org): http://pdepend.org/news/pdepend-1.1.0-released.html

Answer (score 1):

As stated in http://pdepend.org/documentation/handbook/installation/pear-installer.html:

```
$ pear install pdepend/PHP_Depend-beta
```

Note the "beta" in it. By default, the pear installer only installs software marked as *stable*, which phpdepend is not.